# Mimic the Excel LookUp function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to mimic what a the Excel lookup function do but in SQL:

```
LOOKUP(recAge+1, 'reference'!refAge, 'reference'refVal')
```

I have 2 tables, `records` with a `recAge` column, and `Gender` which is the "reference" table and it has three columns: `refAge`, `refVal` and `Gender`.

What I want to do is get the `refValue` from the "reference" table where:

1. `'refAge' == 'recAge'+1` and if that is not applicable then I should get the smallest value close to it.
2. Both have the same gender

Here is an example of what I have and what should be the final result:

| recAge | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | F |
| 1.5 | M |
| 2 | F |
| 2.5 | M |

The "reference" table:

| refAge | refVal | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | F |
| 1.5 | 17 | F |
| 2 | 12 | F |
| 2.5 | 11 | F |
| 1 | 10 | M |
| 1.5 | 15 | M |
| 2 | 14 | M |
| 2.5 | 19 | M |

I should be getting this as the result:

| Gnder | recAge | refVal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | 1 | 12 |
| M | 1.5 | 19 |
| F | 2 | 11 >>> since 2+1= 3 and this does not exist in the Reference table |
| M | 2.5 | 19 >>> same as the previous |

I am stuck on how to join the two tables since there is no common key to apply the join on, I tried the following query but it only displays values of equal ages between the two tables.

```
WITH Ltable AS 
(
    SELECT
        Gender, Age, refVal
    FROM 
        Records  
    FULL JOIN
        Reference ON Records.Age = Reference.Age
    WHERE  
        (Records.Age+1 = Reference.Age) 
        OR (Records.Age + 1 > Reference.Age)
)
```

but it only shows me the (Records.Age+1 = Reference.Age) values and the reset of the ages are not matched with their closest smallest reference age to it.

I also tried the join on the gender but the same is happening.

Comment: Why are you using a FULL join? Are there refAges that don't exist in recAge?

Comment: What is the *actual* logic? Databases aren't Excel sheets and even LOOKUP is just a tool, not the actual problem or requirement. What works in Excel for a few thousand rows will not only run slowly in a database, they'll affect the entire application

Answer (score 3):

You can use correlated sub-query for this and fetch the TOP 1 result for each row, based on your condition:

```
SELECT 
  rec.Gender
, rec.recAge
, (
     SELECT TOP 1 refVal
     FROM Reference ref 
     WHERE rec.Gender = ref.Gender
     --ORDER BY ABS(rec.recAge + 1 - ref.refAge)
     AND ref.refAge <= rec.recAge+1
     ORDER BY ref.refAge DESC
  ) AS refVal
FROM Records rec
```

I am not sure I got your logic correctly, you might need to tweak, but you should get the idea.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4qzrcTjl)

Comment: Gave it a thumbs up as a good answer - but if I'm reading the question correctly the OP wants not the closest, but the closest /and smaller/ number (i.e., the closest value that is not greater than the recAge). If this is true, a quick tweak to your answer (e.g., add `AND ref.refAge <= rec.recAge+1` to the WHERE clause, then just `ORDER BY ref.refAge DESC`) should do it.

Comment: @seanb Yeah, I had same thoughts after posting it, but got distracted before editing.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm correct with the logic/requirements, but I think I am. If the OP just wants the closest though (e.g., 'smallest difference') then no tweaks required to your answer.

Comment: There are both variants in the fiddle, and in comment.